# Why isn't my error being returned in my express response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a default error handler setup in my express application as so.

```
 app.use(function unhandledErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500).json({
     error: err
   });
 });
```

However whenever I call a route and an error is thrown I am getting a response that looks like this.

```
{
  "error": {}
}
```

Can someone help my understand why express is returning my error as an empty Object?

Comment: Have you defined that middleware function at the very end of your routes?

Comment: Yep, It is otherwise working exactly as expected. If I change the `{error: err}` to `{error: err.stack}` I get what I am expecting, I am more curious about the mechanisms of the Error Object / express that are causing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `Error` instances are being shown as empty objects is because the normal properties (e.g. `.message`, `.stack`, etc.) on an `Error` object are not set as enumerable and `JSON.stringify()` (used by `res.json()`) ignores non-enumerable properties.

If you just want to send the message portion (not including the stack trace), you could do this instead:

```
res.json({ error: err.message });
```

or

```
res.json({ error: { message: err.message } });
```

Otherwise if you want to include other custom, enumerable properties that may have been tacked onto the `Error` instance, you could make `.message` enumerable and then use the same code you're using now:

```
Object.defineProperty(err, 'message', { enumerable: true });
res.json({ error: err });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick thorough answer!